# Error trying to inherit from pygame.midi

Tags: python, inheritance, pygame

I am working on a program, and I want to have a class that inherits everything from pygame.midi. However, when I attempt to do this, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/KelsenHazelwood/Documents/School/CS 23000/qBasicMusicMaker.py", line 5, in 
    class userSong (midi):
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Here is the code I've been working with:

```
from pygame import midi

class userSong (midi):
    def __init__ (self):
        pass
        #super (midi,self).__init__()

def main():
    k = userSong ()

main ()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pygame.midi](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html) is a [module](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html).  You can't inherit from a module, only classes.  You could import every class in `pygame.midi`, and inherit from `one` of them.   Technically, it would be possible to inherit from `all of them`, but that's a terrible idea - the functionality is split into various classes for a reason.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Thanks! This is my first project with modules so I guess I didn't really understand that